# Parsing JSON with jQuery's ajax method

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jslint, jsonlint

I'm currently fiddling around with JSON - but I can't get jQuery's `$.ajax` method to parse my feed.

I've validated the feed with JSONLint, and the JS with JSLint - it appears to be fine.

Check out my jsfiddle-example here: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/RqgRf/

Any hint on what could be wrong is highly appreciated :)

Comment: Uhm, the example is missing. Btw, the error method on jQuery's ajax method might give you an idea of what could be wrong.

Comment: Example added ;) I'll check out the error-method.

Comment: Your example is saved with MooTools enabled instead of jQuery

Comment: Fixed that - still no success.

Comment: Have you tried loading from a static source instead of DropBox?

Comment: It works but didn't a moment ago, what did you change? It wasn't shared?

Comment: @Viruzzo Hmm, weird, it still doesn't work here.

Comment: @shanethehat I've changed the source of the json-file: http://jsfiddle.net/timkl/RqgRf/

Comment: @timkl I meant the file URL, not the Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `$.ajax()` call is allowed to load content from external sites.

Comment: That was it! Thx a lot for helping me out :)